# PHP query MySQL function string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I have a SQL variable:**

```
$paramArray = ['test@gmail.com', 111];

$sql = sprintf(SELECT %s(%s) as row from dual,
            'test',
            implode(', ', $paramArray)
);
```

**I get a string like this:**

```
"SELECT test(test@gmail.com, 111) from dual";
```

But I get an error.

**How can I get string like this:**

```
"SELECT test('test@gmail.com', 111) from dual";
```

Comment: Do you have a PHP function called `test()` ? Please state your objective clearly.

Comment: Add quotes where you need. I don't see the problem.

Comment: seems like comments can be compared to mere peasants, while answers are the cream of the crop; so... you going to answer these guys? Your code isn't valid, there.

Answer (score 0):

You can map a function that checks whether the element is a number, and wraps quotes around it if not.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT %s(%s) AS row FROM dual",
        'test',
        implode(', ', array_map(function($x) {
            return is_numeric($x) ? $x : "'$x'";
        });
);
```